# JPA entity and Database Table mapping Validation constraint(s) violated

Tags: jpa, database-design, netbeans

**I have two table:**

```
 CREATE TABLE [LeTYPE](
    [LeNAME] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Le_DESC] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [LeFOR] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LeTYPE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LeNAME] ASC
)
)

CREATE TABLE [Le](
    [SN] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LeNAME_FK] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Le_SN] [int] NULL,
    [LOWERRANGE] [float] NOT NULL,
    [UPPERRANGE] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Le_DESC] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [COLOR] [varchar](45) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Le_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SN] ASC
))
GO


ALTER TABLE [Le]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Le_LeTYPE] FOREIGN KEY([LeNAME_FK])
REFERENCES [LeTYPE] ([LeNAME])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Le] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Le_LeTYPE]
GO
```

***One tuple in LETYPE will have many LE.***

JPA Entity generated by netbeans:

```
     public class Letype implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String Lename;
    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "Le_DESC", length = 500)
    private String LeDesc;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String Lefor;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "LenameFk", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Le> LeList;
}



public class Le implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer sn;
    @Column(name = "Le_SN")
    private Integer LeSn;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double lowerrange;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double upperrange;
    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "Le_DESC", length = 500)
    private String LeDesc;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(length = 45)
    private String color;
    @JoinColumn(name = "LeNAME_FK", referencedColumnName = "LeNAME", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Letype LenameFk;
}
```

***Now, What I wanted was if I add a LETYPE from JSF view I would like to add multiple LE also at the same time.***

```
LETYPE 
      -LE1
      -LE2
      -LE3
```

The structure of entities generated by netbean has `letypeList` with in Le and not the opposite.
Is my database structure wrong or How to do it right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes i feel like you got wrong relationship in database between `LE` and `LETYPE`.

Current relation from JPA perspective is treated as **One** `LE` can have **Many** `LETYPE` that is why you see below code in `LE` entity class.

```
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "LeFk")
     private List<Letype> letypeList;
```

But it is wrong, you need **Reverse** relation i.e, **One** `LETYPE` can have **Many** `LE` (One-To-Many).

Basically your `database structure` is wrong I guess, you have to maintain **FK** column in `LE` table, where as currently you maintaining in `LETYPE`.

In database world, **FK** column always resides in **Many** side , in your case i.e. `LE` table.

**What to do now**

- Remove FK column in `LETYPE` table
- Add FK column in `LE` table referring to `LETYPE` table primary key
- Generate JPA Entity again
- Then you see right JPA code with right relation ship.

I hope then you should be able to do what you need.

Comment: i will try and revert back

Comment: Great. looking forward that it helps you :).

Comment: I have updated the question I have some error while updating saying Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. I know it is related to some constraint but I am unable to find.

Comment: Can you show the part related to that callback method and the related error/exception ?

Answer (score 1):

*"What I wanted was if I add a LETYPE from JSF view I would like to add multiple LE also at the same time"*  means that the LETYPE can be seen as the component class, and the LE as the composite class, so you should reverse the mapping annotations. To illustrate this and what @Jayasagar well explained in addition, the two classes's forms look like :

**Letype.java :**

```
public class Letype implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="letype")
    private List<Le> les;
}
```

**Le.java :**

```
public class Le implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Letype_FK", referencedColumnName = "LENAME")
    private Letype letype;
}
```